# python - pyodbc setting for increase package size in stored procedure params

Tags: sql-server, django, python-2.7, pyodbc

I'm using Python2.7 with `pyodbc==3.0.7` for connecting to SQL Server.

Everything is OK, but when I call a stored procedure with a string parameter that has 480 characters, it returns below error:

Code:

```
cursor.execute("{CALL SP_NAME(?)}", (param))
```

Error:

> The driver did not supply an error!

But when I call `SP` with less character count, it works.

So, how can I increase transfer package size in pyodbc?

**Note**: This problem does not exists in Windows OS, but it appears in Unix OS.

Comment: A few ideas. First, have you tried pyodbc 3.0.10? I've upgrade without issue. Perhaps try sending it as unicode? Any chance of trying it on Python 3? The reason I ask is the documentation contains the ODBC Datatype to python datatype translation here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Data-Types It might help narrow down the problem. Can you include more code for a solid repro?

Comment: Here's the documentation for 3.0.10 I'm referencing: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Data-Types

Comment: @FlipperPA Thanks for your response. i tried pyodbc 3.0.10 too, but it doesn't work yet. about python3, it's not a good idea. i have so many modules that working with python2.7. i calculated the max param length in pyodbc, that is 256 character for string. it doesn't work with more that this value.now i'm reading your reference. if i got some useful things, let you know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum Length of `pyodbc` module is 255 characters in each transferring in Unix OS. i checked some attributes like `packet size` in "connection string" through this reference [http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/](http://SQL%20Server%20connection%20strings), but it doesn't influence.

If you need to increase that, You need to change unixODBC-devel package in Unix base systems. Or decrease your packet size in each SP calling.